# Chrome 91 update broke all table views

Tags: google-chrome, html-table

I've been doing web development for a few years now and have never had a Chrome update break my apps. Chrome build `Version 91.0.4472.101 (Official Build) (x86_64)` broke every table layout for Windows and Mac users while i was on vacation. The break has something to do with setting the `width` on table columns. As a temporary workaround I had to change `width` setting on all tables in all apps to stop using `px` or `vw` for `width` for a table column. To resolve i had to make them all use `%` Like `width: 15%;`. Otherwise the view has header columns not lining up with the data or in some cases entire columns of data would not show on the page. The problem is only in Chrome....everything still works fine in Firefox and MS Edge.

I'm more familiar with me or my team mistakenly pushing a breaking change into production. This is the first time I've seen stable web apps in production break because of a change in chrome. How can i prevent this type of catastrophe in the future?.....or is this something i couldn't have done anything to prevent?

I stripped down an app to just enough code to show an example. In [example repo](https://github.com/travis5491811/chrome91break), run `npm install && npm run serve` then open your browser to `localhost:8080` then see text at line 23 in `src/views/Table.vue`

```
.item-table .example-class {
  width: 4vw; // worked great for years, stopped working after chrome 91.0.4472.101
  // width: 150px; // worked great for years, stopped working after chrome 91.0.4472.101
  // width: 4%; // only thing that seems to work now
}
```

All other related table styling is in `src/assets/css/table.scss`

[image]

Note that I'm not using it but [datatables users](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/68506/latest-google-chrome-91-0-4472-77-breaks-fixed-columns-with-complex-headings) are experiencing similar problems.

Comment: You really need to supply a concrete example of HTML that is rendered differently in Chrome 91 to earlier versions.

Comment: @Tom I added a example repo that can reproduce the problem and updated the post.

Comment: This issue is also reported in some third party products.
https://www.intersoftsolutions.com/Community/WebGrid/Grouped-areas-not-displayed-correctly-after-chrome-being-updated/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is related to the rewrite of table rendering in Chrome 91 (TablesNG): https://developer.chrome.com/blog/tablesng/

If I go to chrome://flags search for TableNG and disable it your test page appears correctly.

There are a few bugs reported: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=TablesNG&can=2 you might try logging one yourself.

As for how can you stop this happening in the future, I doubt you can if a chunk of the browser is rewritten and changes its behaviour.

Comment: FYI the workaround suggested by Erik helped me. Adding a print rule to turn flex container into block fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Came across this after company upgraded to 91 from 88. Not sure if this answers this exact question but if you come through here, I had my table container nested in a flex layout that set {display flex; flex 1;} on the div wrapping my {display: table} div container. Just deselected display flex in devTools and boom, Table went back to normal. Not sure what Chrome did to make this happen but it solved our issue.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you. I don't know why I can't find more information on this topic on the internet.