# Datatables Columns not aligning when using ScrollX, ScrollY

Tags: datatables-1.10

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cu1hr3jp/)

```
$('#tblCCR').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  ordering: false,
  sorting: false,
  fixedColumns: {
    leftColumns: 3
  },
  scrollX: true,
  scrollY: '55vh',
  scrollCollapse: true,
  buttons: [
    'excelHtml5',
    {
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      orientation: 'landscape',
      widths: 'auto',
      customize: function(doc) {
        doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 4;
        doc.styles.title.fontSize = 4;
        doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 4;
        doc.styles.tableFooter.fontSize = 4;
        doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'left';
        doc.styles.title.bold = true;
        doc.styles.tableHeader.bold = true;
        doc.styles.tableHeader.color = '#ffffff';
        doc.styles.tableHeader.fillColor = '#666666';
        doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.fillColor = '#ffffff';
        doc.styles.tableBodyEven.fillColor = '#e9e9e9';
      }
    },
  ],
  language: {
    emptyTable: "No data available - Have you selected a class or cohort?"
  },
  dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 text-right'B>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>",
});
```

I'm in desperate need of fresh eyes, I've spent about 10 hours trying to find the issue and cannot. In the above fiddle the columns do not align and it appears to be due to ScrollX and ScrollY -- if I comment them out everything aligns. In the past I know there were issues using ScrollX & ScrollY with fixedColumns, but I thought that had been fixed. Plus, I have at least a dozen other reports that use the combination of ScrollX, ScrollY, and fixedColumns and they work perfectly.

To paraphrase Princess Leigh: Help me Stack Overflow...you're my only hope...

Answer (score 0):

Somebody on the DataTables forums shared a post that explains what's happening, it has to do specifically with the latest release of Chrome (91).  There's a stackoverflow post already addressing this issue and (kind of) providing a solution or proof of concept.

[Chrome 91 update broke all table views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977643/chrome-91-update-broke-all-table-views)